# How to connect to a MySQL database through ODBC from Qt application?

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, qt, odbc

I have a freshly-installed MySQL server, which listens on localhost:3306. What is the correct way to connect to it from my Qt application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that I need to add MySQL to the ODBC data sources. I did that after following this video tutorial - https://youtu.be/K3GZidOwGmM.

After I had added the DSN, I successfully connected to the MySQL server using this code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};DATABASE=test;");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("password");
if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
} else {
    qDebug("success");
}
```

**Note:** You will need to replace `MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver` with the actual value listed in your DSN window. I got mine from here:

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that if your app is 32bit than the MySQL ODBC driver has to be 32bit too. On x64 Windows the ODBC Data Source Administrator for 32 bit drivers is located in SysWOW64 and not in system32.

Comment: This works perfectly, I used the mariadb connector though.