# How to connect Qt C++ program to an online MySQL database through ODBC (without MySQL Qt Driver compiled)

Tags: mysql, qt, connection, odbc, database-connection

I was having the following problem that I resolved casually doing lot of attempts:
I need to connect my Qt application to an online mysql database, so I tried lot of times to connect my program to my database, but things didn't works.
At first I had problems to compile MySql driver for Qt, I followed every guide and topic on the web about that but I got always error, so I decided to use ODBC that it's ready for work without any compilation.
So I followed lot of guides and topics about the connection to MySQL through ODBC in Qt (including this: [How to connect to a MySQL database through ODBC from Qt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165525/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-through-odbc-from-qt-application)) but I got always errors also this time. The official documentation of Qt about this topic lacks and isn't updated but I resolved, with lot of attempts and lot of luck so this is the guide on how to connect Qt application to MySQL online database without compile any driver, let's start:

1. Follow this video: https://youtu.be/K3GZidOwGmM (download ODBC and configure your database as shown)
2. Create/Open your Qt project
3. Add to the .pro file the following line: QT       += sql
4. Write the following code (obviously you have to change the hostname, username, ecc.. my parameters are only an example):

   `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3", "Database"); // VERY IMPORTANT INSERT QODBC3 AND NOT QODBC
   db.setHostName(something.yourhost.com); 
   db.setUserName(myusername);
   db.setDatabaseName(mydatabasename);
   db.setPassword(mypassword);
   if(db.open()){qDebug()<<"Database opened!";}
   else{qDebug() << db.lastError().text();}`
5. If you followed all steps this should work

I spent lot of hours to unterstand how to do this cause to official lack documentation (that doen't work) and cause to lot of versions of Qt..
So i hope this little guide might help all the people that have problems about this topic :)

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have, is it 32- or 64-bit? Also, which Qt version? Which error messages you got?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even though you have a Qt app (maybe for some gui purposes), there's no reason you can't use mysqlpp libraries instead of relying on Qt sql components.

Comment: @MichaelO. I'm using Windows 10 64 bit but I use the MinGW 32 bit compiler. My Qt verion is 5.0.2. During all my attempts I got so many errors that it's inpossible remeber all, but I'm sure that for each one I do lot of researches trying to resolving.. Thank you anyway

Comment: @tinkertime yeah, it'true but Qt sql components are better for multi platform purposes ;)